# CORS and Custom Headers not set in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm trying to set up an Azure API but no matter what I do, the CORS headers are not added to my response.  I've also tried just adding a random header and that isn't working either.

I've seen multiple other posts on S/O and elsewhere and as near as I can tell, my policies are correct.  Is there something else I need to do?  Below is the calculated effective policy for an operation.  This is a simple GET, though I've also tried with a POST with the same results.  When I call the API from Postman and specify my SubscriptionKey in the header, I get back the 201 response specified in my mock policy, but no additional headers.  Fiddler confirms that the response does not contain either the CORS or my `X-WTF` header.
When I call the API from the Test tab in APIM, it also succeeds with the 201 but no additional headers.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <!-- base: Begin Api scope -->
    <cors>
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>*</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
            <method>*</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
            <header>*</header>
        </allowed-headers>
        <expose-headers>
            <header>*</header>
        </expose-headers>
    </cors>
    <!-- base: End Api scope -->
    <mock-response status-code="201" content-type="application/json" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <!-- base: Begin Api scope -->
    <!-- base: Begin Product scope -->
    <!-- base: Begin Global scope -->
    <forward-request />
    <!-- base: End Global scope -->
    <!-- base: End Product scope -->
    <!-- base: End Api scope -->
</backend>
<outbound>
    <!-- base: Begin Api scope -->
    <set-header name="X-WTF" exists-action="override">
        <value>147852</value>
    </set-header>
    <!-- base: End Api scope -->
</outbound>
<on-error />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the cause for that behavior is the `mock-response` policy. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#mock-response), this command *"aborts normal pipeline execution and returns a mocked response to the caller"*, so you seem to end up receiving the exact mocked response, as no other policies are processed.

You can, however, enrich your mocked response either by adding parameters to your `mocked-response` policy or by using the [`return-response`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ReturnResponse) policy.

This [blog post](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2017/09/06/prototyping-how-to-mock-responses-in-api-management/), despite being from 2017, presents these options nicely :)